# How to use cordova.js in another .js intel xdk

Tags: javascript, cordova, intel-xdk

I'm developing an app using Intel XDK with Cordova. I have a .js with all my functions, in that .js I would like to use Cordova's lib, but i just can't. Even importing the cordova.js before importing my .js to my html page I can't use cordova's lib. The only way I can use is creating a tag  in my on html. The project is working with cordova, i'm sure of that because testing the same code in a script tag at my html works just fine. So, how can i use cordova's lib at another javascript?

Every HTML page i do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJS.js">
```

But doesn't work. If I do that in my HTML page:

```
<script> //USE CORDOVA'S LIB HERE </script>
```

It works.

Comment: Are you waiting for `app.ready()`? or `$(function(){ //your code here });`

Comment: I'm using $( document ).ready( function() { //code here }); in my .js.

Comment: Okay.. So this shouldn't be happening. When you open up the debugger/console, do you have any errors? If so, what are they? Can you post the contents of myJS.js? Is _any_ of the code in myJS.js executing? For example, a console.log() located at the top of the file.

Comment: It's working now, but only somethings, I can't check the Internet connection. I'll try more here.